# tkinter mutliplying the price from table

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I am making a simple program for cafe management system that  reads food names as  a buttons from a table also I want to read  the the food price from the table and multiply it by the number of button clicks and then save them into a `Text` how I can do this please

[this is the image that show  where are the two main isues are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w23tO.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random


variable = 1
bttn_clicks=0
button_dict = {}
button_dic = {}
conn = sqlite3.connect('hoteldb.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def showqurec():
   global button,data2
   data2 = readqurec()
   for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
     button= ttk.Button(master, text=dat[0],command=lambda dat=dat:update_count(dat))
     button.grid(row=index+1, column=0,padx=0, pady=0)
     button_dict[dat] = button

def showqado():
    global button,data2
    data2 = readqado()
    for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
        button = ttk.Button(master, text=dat[0],command=lambda dat=dat: update_count(dat))
        button.grid(row=index+1, column=1,pady=0,padx=0)
        button_dict[dat] = button


def showcasho():
   global button,data2
   data2 = readcasho()
   for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
        button=ttk.Button(master, text=dat[0],command=lambda dat=dat:update_count(dat))
       button.grid(row=index+1, column=2,padx=0, pady=0)
       button_dict[dat] = button



def readfromdatabase():
   cur.execute("SELECT qureec.name,qado.name,casho.name FROM qureec,qado,casho")
   return cur.fetchall()
def readqurec():
   cur.execute("SELECT name FROM qureec ")
   return cur.fetchall()

def readqado():
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM qado ")
    return cur.fetchall()

def readcasho():
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM casho ")
    return cur.fetchall()


def update_count(x):
    global bttn_clicks,my_text,price
    my_text=StringVar()
    for name in data2:
        my_text = button_dict[x].cget('text')
    bttn_clicks += 1



def Receipt():
   txtReceipt.delete("1.0", "4.0")
   x = random.randint(10908, 500876)
   randomRef = str(x)
   Receipt_Ref.set("BILL" + randomRef)



   txtReceipt.insert("1.0", 'Receipt Ref: \t\t\t'+Receipt_Ref.get()+"\t\t"+DateofOrder.get()+"\n")
   txtReceipt.insert("2.0", 'Items\t\t'+'Quantity\t\t\t'+"Price \n\n")
   if variable !=0:
       txtReceipt.insert(END, str(my_text)+'\t\t'+str(bttn_clicks)+'\t\t\t'+""+str(bttn_clicks*3)+"\n")










master=Tk()
master.geometry('630x350+100+200')
master.title('Records')
Label = Button(master, text="meal", width=10,command=showqurec)
Label.grid(row=0, column=0)

BMILabel = Button(master, text="tea", width=10,command=showqado)
BMILabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

stateLabel = Button(master, text="fast food", width=10,command=showcasho)
stateLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)

lblReceipt = Button(master,text="Get Receipt:",anchor='w',command=Receipt)
lblReceipt.grid(row=0,column=4,sticky=W)
txtReceipt = Text(master,bg="white",width=47,height=17.5)
txtReceipt.grid(row=1,column=4,rowspan=4,columnspan=40)

Receipt_Ref=StringVar()
DateofOrder = StringVar()
master.mainloop()
```

Now  I declared the prices but how I can get them from database
 I also have another of buttons clicks are incrementing on every buttons clicked how on specied button

Comment: As you have seen, you don't get good answers to your questions. One reason it the you are not making it easy to help you. 

Your code does not run! We try to find problems in your code by running it and looking at the output and the error messages. If you don't provide code that runs we will have to guess how it's supposed to work and we may be wrong. 

You provide no sample data. You retrieve data with `cur.fetchall()` but we don't know what that data looks like. Again, we'll have to guess. 

It would be easier if you provide these things for us.

Comment: @figbeam thanks I shared all the code please try  and again help me how I can get the price from database and multiply it the number of button clicks

Comment: You have several functions that reads from database. Please swap the database reads for example data. I haven't got your database.

Comment: @figbeam I have three tables for breakfast ,lunch and dinner so all several function are reading from these three tables   I read  these names as buttons but I don't want to read the prices in buttons I just want to make  dictionary and then  use use to multiply the the number of buttons clicks in the Text box

Comment: @figbeam any help or suggestions please

Comment: Ok. So you have tables. But I don't have tables. Can you please provide the tables. I have difficulties running your code, which uses the tables, if I haven't got the tables.

Comment: @figbeam thanks bro the tables are just containing food name and price if you can connect your own database or where my I share with you

Comment: I don't have any database installed and I'm not sure to guess what data might be like as I don't understand the words: qureec, qado, casho, or how they relate to eachother in the database structure. Please give me an example of how they look or I can't help you. You are making it very difficult to help you.

Comment: @figbeam thanks bro for all your respect I edited the the question and I added an image for simple description for easier to understand    and the words qureec and other just names for a meal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the name on the buttons instead of just the first letter you have to set the name to the whole string, not just the first position:

```
button = ttk.Button(master, text=dat, command ...
                     (instead of dat[0])
```

for each of the categories: meal, tea and fast food.

I'm not getting a clear picture of how you want this to work in the end. Do you want the receipt to be updated for each product or only in the end. The function `update_count()` looks very strange.

I would recommend using a dict to store products and prices. This will make price lookup easy. As long as the application if fairly small I think a global variable would be preferrable.

```
products = {'Soup': 2.40, 'Fish': 3.10, 'Beef': 3.55, 'Pizza': 2.70}
```

Take a look at the example code below, try to run it and think about how you want the rest to work. Should the receipt be updated each time you push a button? Should the receipt be ordered in any way? What if you want to remove something from the receitp?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random

variable = 1
bttn_clicks=0
button_dict = {}
button_dic = {}
#conn = sqlite3.connect('hoteldb.db')
#c = conn.cursor()
products = {}   # Dictionary of products and prices
tally = []      # List of ordered products

def showqurec():
    global button, data2
    data2 = readqurec()
    for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
        button = ttk.Button(master, text=dat, command=lambda dat=dat: update_count(dat))
        button.grid(row=index+1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)
        button_dict[dat] = button

def showqado():
    global button, data2
    data2 = readqado()
    for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
        button = ttk.Button(master, text=dat, command=lambda dat=dat: update_count(dat))
        button.grid(row=index+1, column=1, pady=0, padx=0)
        button_dict[dat] = button

def showcasho():
    global button, data2
    data2 = readcasho()
    for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
        button = ttk.Button(master, text=dat, command=lambda dat=dat: update_count(dat))
        button.grid(row=index+1, column=2,padx=0, pady=0)
        button_dict[dat] = button

def readfromdatabase(): # This function is never called...
    return None     
def readqurec():    # Get Meal from database
    meal = {'Soup': 2.40, 'Fish': 3.10, 'Beef': 3.55, 'Pizza': 2.70}
    products.update(meal)
    return meal
def readqado():     # Get Tea from database
    tea = {'Tea': 1.20, 'Coffee': 1.00, 'Soda': 1.65}
    products.update(tea)
    return tea
def readcasho():    # Get Fast food from database
    fast_food = {'Hamburger': 1.80,'Hot dog': 1.45,'Pasta': 1.65}
    products.update(fast_food)
    return fast_food

def update_count(x):
    global bttn_clicks,my_text,price
    purchase = [x,products[x]]  # Get the product and price
    tally.append(purchase)      # Add this purchase to the tally
    print(purchase)
    # Leaving the rest of the function as is ...
    my_text=StringVar()
    for name in data2:
        my_text = button_dict[x].cget('text')
    bttn_clicks += 1

def Receipt():
   txtReceipt.delete("1.0", "4.0")
   x = random.randint(10908, 500876)
   randomRef = str(x)
   Receipt_Ref.set("BILL" + randomRef)

   txtReceipt.insert("1.0", 'Receipt Ref: \t\t\t'+Receipt_Ref.get()+"\t\t"+DateofOrder.get()+"\n")
   txtReceipt.insert("2.0", 'Items\t\t'+'Quantity\t\t\t'+"Price \n\n")
   if variable !=0:
       txtReceipt.insert(END, str(my_text)+'\t\t'+str(bttn_clicks)+'\t\t\t'+""+str(bttn_clicks*3)+"\n")


master=Tk()
master.geometry('630x350+100+200')
master.title('Records')
Label = Button(master, text="meal", width=10,command=showqurec)
Label.grid(row=0, column=0)

BMILabel = Button(master, text="tea", width=10,command=showqado)
BMILabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

stateLabel = Button(master, text="fast food", width=10,command=showcasho)
stateLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)

lblReceipt = Button(master,text="Get Receipt:",anchor='w',command=Receipt)
lblReceipt.grid(row=0,column=4,sticky=W)

txtReceipt = Text(master,bg="white",width=47,height=17.5)
txtReceipt.grid(row=1,column=4,rowspan=4,columnspan=40)

Receipt_Ref=StringVar()
DateofOrder = StringVar()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for all your tries and respect     yes you can use these data , so how I can enter the price in the readqurecp into the Text

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look and run it and see what you think.

Comment: yes perfectly thank you but still  what if from database like      "cursor.execute("SELECT name,price FROM food")"

Comment: thanks again but if can try if it is coming from table

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the syntax for getting data from the database. Surely there must be a SQL forum in which to ask that.

Comment: thanks  again really you help me greatly , if I ask you onother question ,if I press meal for example how I can desapear the buttons of tea and fastfood

Comment: You can remove any widget with `widget.grid_remove()`, but you will have to remember which buttons are in which column. The button will still exist, and you can show it again with `widget.grid()`. It will remember where it was placed.